# WPF : Cannot connect to directory

Tags: .net, wpf, active-directory

I have a `WPF` app connecting to `Active Directory` for authentication. Its working fine on some computers it doesn't work on some computers.

The environment is `Windows XP` with `.Net 4.0 Client Profile & Extended` installed. I've researched all over the internet & couldn't find an answer that's related to the error that I'm getting.

The exception that I get for the users that can't connect to AD is:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x00005011): Unknown error (0x5011)
>     at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext()
>     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.GetNextSearchResult()
>     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.MoveNextMemberSearcher()
>     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.MoveNext()
>     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNConstraintLinkedAttrSet.MoveNext()
>     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>
>     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.FindResultEnumerator`1.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: **Show us the code you're using** that causes this exception !!

Comment: Have you looked at the properties for your DirectoryServicesCOMException object? Does it contain an InnerException with more details? Since it is working on some machine and not on others, I suspect either a machine configuration issue, or an LDAP configuration issue. Are you always using the same credentials when testing?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Philipp.. there is no more details that the exception throws.. The weird part is, not all end user computers throw the error.. 
Then striking out all the possibilities.. I found that there was a conflict with the versions of .net that is installed in the client computers. They had all the flavors pf  .Net FW. I started removing one by one & left .net 4 which is used by my software & that did the trick. Then I had to narrow it down to .net 1.1 which was the issue.. removing that fixed the issue..